# Stopping animation using .stop() method

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown(5000);
  });
   $("#stop").click(function(){
    $("*:animated").stop();
  });

#panel,#flip
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}


<button id="stop">Stop sliding</button>
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
< div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

The code above only stops the animation .I want to play the animation back on next click ,what should i do? i m a complete beginner.Is there any jquery method to simply start the animation ,if not any trick using jquery code not css3

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop the animation and slide it back up when you click #stop?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a clean plugin

[PAUSE / RESUME ANIMATION (ANIMATE)](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation)

```
$(...).startAnimation(  params, [duration], [easing], [callback] )
$(...).pauseAnimation()
$(...).resumeAnimation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using a plugin you can do something like this:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybWWh/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flip").click(function () {
        $('#panel').stop().slideToggle(2000, function () {});
    });
    $("#stop").click(function () {
        $("#panel").stop();
        if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $('#panel').slideUp(2000);
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        }
        $(this).addClass("open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `$("*:animated").stop();` to `$("*:animated").stop().slideUp();`